# asp.net mvc - display rich text code in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How would you do to display rendered html code like this `<b>short article</b>` and display it as bold **short articl**
in an ASP.net mvc 3 view ?

I tried out `@System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.short_article);` but doesn' t work

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [HtmlHelper.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). It will return markup that is not HTML encoded.

You need to be aware however of the security risks when outputting HTML like this. If a user enters some HTML code that contains Javascript and save it to the database, your page will render and execute this script.

If there is a risk of users entering malicious data for your short_article field you should strip their input based on a whitelist of tags you want to allow.

Comment: It works perfect ! Millions thanks :), the html code is just for retrieving from my database, no update from user, no risk of javascript attack, though thanks for your remark. Thanks again

Comment: Is your code Encoded before you try to use the HTML.Raw function? if it is then the Raw will output the encoded html, not the actual html.